# Cannot succesfully send a particular AJAX request via JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to delete information from my MySQL database using AJAX, but for some reason, the request is not even being sent out to my designated ajax url.

Here is the code being sent:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // Notes Delete
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form#RemoveNote2").submit(function() {
            var ID = $('#ID').attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxdeleteinvoicenote.php",
                    data: "id="+ ID,
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function(result){
                        alert('test');
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the form it is sending from:

```
<form id="RemoveNote2" style="margin: 0px; padding:0px;" method="post">
  <span style="width:80%; display:inline-block;">Test</span>
  <span style="text-align: center; width: 10%; display:inline-block;">
    <input id="ID" type="hidden" value="39">
    <button class="close" type="submit">×</button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Using a tool called Fiddler2, I have noticed that it is not even completing the task of sending to ajaxdeleteinvoicenote.php. Any ideas why?

Comment: did you check with firebug or similar for any javascript errors?

Comment: With `input` elements you better use `.val()`.

Comment: And also correct `datatype` to `dataType`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/CfhHB/. Your script should work by all means. The only option is that there is no such file `ajaxdeleteinvoicenote.php` in the current folder.

Comment: Thanks @VisioN now my comment is *really* redundant...

Comment: @Louis All comments are important. Yours just approves mine and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not JSON type formated. Try to remove the parameter **datatype: "json"**

Have a nice day

Comment: How do you know how the data is formated? OP did not provide his response data.

Comment: Hi, data like "key1=value1&key2=value2" is url/text formatted.  {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'} is a JSON map. Isn't it?

Comment: You mix `dataType` and `data` options. They are used for different things and do not depend on each other. Check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: The doc says : "DataType : The type of data that you're expecting back from the server". My mistake. Thanks

Comment: Also it would be smart to add handler for error. E.g. 
error:function(xhr,err){alert(xhr.responseText);}

Answer (score 0):

please note  its not  `datatype: "json",`

its  `dataType: "json",`

also...
instead of using..

```
var ID = $('#ID').attr('value');
```

its good using the this way...

```
 var ID = $('#ID').val();
```

i think this will solve..

Comment: hope u get the error... or please update your question with the error that shows in the firebug...

Answer (score 0):

You're sending it with the `datatype` option set to JSON, while the actual data is form-urlencoded: `data: "id="+ ID,` in JSON would read `{"id":"123"}`. You're best off dropping the datatype (jQuery is smart enought to figure out how to send the data correctly) and drop the 'id=' bit, just send `{id:$('#ID').value}` as is.

Objects needn't be JSON.stringified when using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Mozilla firebug and check included jQuery version. Your code is working fine for me.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<form id="RemoveNote2" style="margin: 0px; padding:0px;" method="post">
  <span style="width:80%; display:inline-block;">Test</span>
  <span style="text-align: center; width: 10%; display:inline-block;">
    <input id="ID" type="hidden" value="39">
    <button class="close" type="submit">X<button>
  </span>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> // Notes Delete
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form#RemoveNote2").submit(function() {
            var ID = $('#ID').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxdeleteinvoicenote.php",
                    data: "id="+ ID,
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function(result){
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

In "ajaxdeleteinvoicenote.php" add below line.

```
<?php
echo $_POST['id'];die;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form#RemoveNote2").submit(function() {
                //e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({                   
                    url: "/ajaxdeleteinvoicenote.php", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { id : $(this).find('#ID').val() },                        
                    success: function(result){
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed ajaxdeleteinvoicenote.php and the page which sends the content in the same folder?
Also remove comma(,) from last property like:

```
 datatype: "json"
```